# How to inject a bean into a Spring Condition class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-4

I am defining conditions that I will check to dynamically load one of the two implementations of my service interface later.

```
@Component
public class IsPolicyEnabled implements Condition {

    @Autowired
    private MyProperties props;

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext arg0, AnnotatedTypeMetadata arg1) {
        return props.isPolicyEnabled();
    }

}
```

And

```
@Component
public class MyProperties {...}
```

And

```
@Service
@Conditional(IsPolicyEnabled.class)
public class ServiceA implements Service {...}
```

However, I am running into a runtime error as.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xyz.utils.IsPolicyEnabled.matches(IsPolicyEnabled.java:9)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:88)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:71)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isConditionMatch(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:515)
```

Basically, it failed to initialize props object that has been auto-wired inside the condition implementation. Is that not allowed?

How can I auto wire another dependency inside the condition implementation since my condition evaluation depends on a value provided by that dependency?

Answer (score 10):

> Conditions are checked **immediately before** the bean-definition is due to be registered [...]
>
> <sup>[`Condition`, Spring Framework 5.0.8.RELEASE API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html)</sup>

You can't inject a bean into a `Condition` instance because there are no bean-definitions in the context yet<sup>1</sup>.

Moreover, you are not supposed to work with beans within `Condition` classes:

> Conditions must follow the same restrictions as `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and **take care to never interact with bean instances**.
>
> <sup>[`Condition`, Spring Framework 5.0.8.RELEASE API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html)</sup>

You should rethink the design because

> [...] my condition evaluation depends on a value provided by that dependency.

indicates that it's not quite right.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Precisely speaking, there are a few beans already registered by Spring for its own needs.</sup>

Comment: "my condition evaluation depends on a value provided by that dependency." Why do you say so? As an example, say there's a DB table that contains a value that drives which type of service to connect to (say JMS or Kafka). In order to tell spring "initialize JMS" or "initialize Kafka", I need a bean that can access DB to read that value, which in turn may need e.g. `JdbcTemplate` or so. How would that initialization be conditioned without those beans?

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

1) There is no injection for Condition classes

Solution is to retrieve beans from ConditionContext:

```
@Component
public class IsPolicyEnabled implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        MyProperties props = context.getBeanFactory().getBean(MyProperties.class);

        return props.isPolicyEnabled();
    }
}
```

2) Condition initialization happens very early

Trying to retrieve beans from ConditionContext fails with `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type ...` because condition check happens very early in the Spring lifecycle.

A solution is to have two Spring contexts:

- A parentContext which defines only `MyProperties`
- A childContext which defines the rest of the application and has parentContext as its parent

So when the Condition is invoked, `MyProperties` is already created in the parent context:

```
ApplicationContext parentContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyProperties.class);
ApplicationContext childContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
childContext.setParent(parent);
childContext.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
childContext.refresh();

Service service = childContext.getBean(Service.class);
// do something with service
```

Comment: I understand your points, but for the part (2), I don't understand where to place that code to initialize the parent context with the properties class, neither how to make it initialized then for the part (1). Thx!